# Printing tables in Java

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print off the following table. When I run the program only 3 columns print off..am I missing something?:

```
static Object[][] table = null;
table = new String[PricesArray.pricesArray.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < PricesArray.pricesArray.size(); i++) {
    table[i] = new String[] { 
        PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getDate(), Double.toString(PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getDailyOpen()), Double.toString(
        PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getDailyHigh()),
        Double.toString(PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getDailyLow()),
        Double.toString(PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getDailyClose()),
        Double.toString(PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getVolume()),
        Double.toString(PricesArray.pricesArray.get(i).getAdjClose())};
    }

    for (final Object[] row : table) {
            System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s\n", row);

    }
```

Comment: You only have 3 formatted strings in your `sysoutformat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   for (final Object[] row : table) {
            System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s\n", row);

    }
```

It looks like in the print statement you are only printing three strings from the row. Have you tried adding 4 more '%15s' to the format function or something to that extent?

Comment: @NikB Click the green checkmark to the left of the answer.